# what is the meaning of tslint: "Warning: The 'no-use-before-declare' rule requires type information"?

Tags: angular, typescript, tslint

What is the meaning of tslint: "Warning: The 'no-use-before-declare' rule requires type information."? I did some basic googling but I'm not clear on what this means or its implications.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**Update**! Since this question was asked, the `--type-check` flag has been deprecated so you should be able use:

```
tslint --project tsconfig.json src/**/**.ts
```

Original answer below.

I believe that this means you can't enable the `no-use-before-declare` rule unless you run with the `--type-check` and the `--project` flags. It must depend on something that happens when those flags are passed in order to determine rule violations.

```
tslint --type-check --project tslint.json src/**/**.ts
```

Comment: looks like that rule is mainly a validation check when using the var keyword:

https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-use-before-declare/

if the var-keyword-forbidden rule is enabled then it seems that this rule can be disabled right?

Comment: Precisely - TypeScript already warns you about `let` and `const` violations. The only reason it doesn't warn you about it with `var` is because variables declared with `var` get hoisted, so they are _technically_ declared before they used.

Comment: Note: `--type-check` is deprecated. You only need `--project` to enable rules which need type information (TSLint v5.10.0).

Comment: It should be `tslint --project tsconfig.json …` not `tslint.json`.

Answer (score 6):

The rule is discouraged, since modern TypeScript do not use it and is slow to compute. Acording to [this page](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-use-before-declare/):

> This rule is primarily useful when using the var keyword since the compiler will automatically detect if a block-scoped let and const variable is used before declaration. Since most modern TypeScript doesn’t use var, this rule is generally discouraged and is kept around for legacy purposes. It is slow to compute, is not enabled in the built-in configuration presets, and should not be used to inform TSLint design decisions.

Answer (score 6):

If you see this warning in VSCode, just delete this rule from `tslint.json`, as the [README](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-tslint/blob/master/tslint/README.md#faq) file in `vscode-tslint` plugin says:

> Since tslint version 5 the rule no-unused-variable requires type information. Rules with type information are currently not supported by vscode-tslint, pls see issue #70. The recommended work around is to enable the TypeScript compiler options noUnusedLocals and noUnusedParameters in your tsconfig.json file.

Answer (score 4):

With **TSLint v5.10.0** and above, you need to point TSLint to your [TypeScript configuration](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) file. You can do that by using the `--project` flag:

```
tslint --project tsconfig.json --config tslint.json \"src/**/*.ts\"
```

Be careful, because it's easy to mix up `tsconfig.json` and `tslint.json` as some users [already experienced](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/3643#issuecomment-358220473).

All TSLint CLI options are [documented here](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/usage/cli/). The usage of `--type-check` is not needed anymore as it got deprecated in [TSLint v5.8.0](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/releases/tag/5.8.0).